# Find 2 lists of equal sum out of a larger list

Tags: java, algorithm

Ok so basically i have a list or an array of integers

List = (1,3,22,17,22,4,15,40)

And i need to find two lists like this:

List1 = (1,3,17,4,15,22) ... Sum = 62

List2 = (22,40) ... Sum = 62

All integers should be used, an integer should be in either List1 or List2

---- my first thought ----

```
Choose the largest nb i.e 40 and try to find integers equal to 40 and add 
to the second list ... But that's not the way ...
```

The above list is an example list ... I should be able to find List1 and List2 if possible for any given list.

Comment: OK. You already know one way how **not** to do it.  Continue your research. Do not forget that Google search still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to find the sum of all the elements of the list. This will always be twice the sum of the two sublists you're looking for. Using your example, the sum of (1,3,22,17,22,4,15,40) is 124, which is twice of 62.

So now you're looking for a set of numbers within the list that sums to 62. You don't have to worry about finding two sets (if you find one, the remaining numbers will definitely sum to 62 as well). I'd do this algorithmically - first look for a set of size 1 whose elements sum to 62 (i.e., go through the list and check if any number is 62). If such a number exists, you're done. If not, next look for sets of size 2. This is tricky because you'll have to look at all possible combinations. Since you have 7 numbers, there are (7*6)/2 = 21 possibilities. If any of those are 62, you're done. If not, move on to checking sets of size 3. And so on, until you reach size 7/2 (you're done at 3 in this case). Obviously with large sets this process will involve a lot of computation and comparison; it can be optimized with a few shortcuts but the basic algorithm is the same.

If in the end, no subsets summing to 62 are found, it's because no such subsets exist.

Comment: Or you can sort the array for less number of comparisons.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay You can optimize in a lot of ways, yes

Answer (score 1):

In general your problem is an NP-hard problem, meaning that probably no fast (polynomial time) solution exists as the size of your array n grows. However if your numbers are relatively small integers (meaning that the sum of their absolute values is on the order of about 1 billion or 10 billion or less depending on how much memory you have), you can use dynamic programming. Basically for the first k elements of your array, you store all the possible sums you can make with subsets of these k elements. You increase k incrementally by taking all sums formed by subsets of the first k elements and then either adding the (k+1)th element of your array or not, which grows the set of obtainable sums. Assuming your n numbers are integers, the total complexity of this approach is O(nM) where M is the total sum of the absolute values of elements in your array. If you run out of memory you can use disk space to store obtainable subsets but that will make the running time slower obviously; however, using disk space you can handle arrays of numbers whose absolute values add up to on the order of 1 trillion or more depending on how much disk space you have